# Working with a web and app server at the same time?

Tags: web-services

How does a company like Facebook for example create a web server that is fully functional but also has an application server that can work in tangent with it(or at lease that's what I think they are doing). I am new to programming and computer science in general and just made my first web server, but then it occurred to me something. How are company able to have you comment on something on your phone/tablet and then switch to a laptop later see the effects of your phone. They both have different servers from my understanding. (I used apache as my web server) facebook is an app that I think would have to use an application server while the website itself is just a HTTP web server. how?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly special about different types of servers.  Servers are just computers connected to a network that take input and give output.  In the case of a web server, it is programmed to provide HTML when a query is made of it.  An application server is programmed to provide a response too, but instead of HTML it will probably be a [serialized object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms233843.aspx) of some kind to provide data for the application to work with.  However there is nothing stopping an app from querying a web server (in fact, that is exactly what your browser does - an app that gets web pages!)

In the example you gave though, you are missing a critical piece of the puzzle, and that is the database.  Facebook (and almost all systems) will have a central database that is used by both its application servers and its web servers.  Here is a very basic diagram of Facebook's architecture:

[image: Facebook Architecture]

When you post a Facebook status on the website, your browser will send that information to a web server.  Since Facebook is huge with millions of requests per minute, the load balancer is needed to route your request to one of many servers.  The Web server will then create an entry in the MySQL database, storing metadata such as the user ID who posted it, the time, as well as the content of text you wrote.

When you check your profile on your phone, the phone app will request a web service to get your statuses.  Many if not most times these days, this is done also with a HTTP request - this is a special URL that provides an endpoint into their system that you can hook into.  Getting user 123456's facebook feed might look something like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/123456/feed HTTP/1.1
```

The web service that handles these requests will then query the database, and return the status you just posted as a serialized object, for the app to deal with as it sees fit.  These so-called [RESTful APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) allow other 3rd party apps to hook into a system and get and post data (with the correct permissions, of course!).  Neat huh?

When you first start to learn computer science you are probably going to store most of your data in memory (i.e. static variables, hardcoded values) or flat files (i.e. reading from a text file).  However in almost all real-world applications you need a dedicated database to handle the massive number of requests.  So this is the reason you can see your status on different devices.  However you access Facebook, you are accessing the same data store.